# in groovy, want to change default parameter based on cron

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cron, jenkins-pipeline

Where i would like to change / decide **default parameter** of Jenkins pipeline job to pass based on `cron` timing.

Something like

- if triggered at **10 AM** pass `default_config = release`
- if triggered at **11 AM** pass `default_config = debug`.

Can i do this in groovy ?

Comment: you could do it.. by providing details in your question you could increase chances to get an answer.

Comment: In this regard you probably need to lean into the Java time libs to evaluate current time and decide what to set.

Comment: why not just have one cron entry for 10am (with one parameter), and another cron entry for 11am with a different parameter?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`Date` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)?